# HBase NoServerForRegionException with region server working fine

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to run a HBase MapReduce job in the pseudo-distributed mode and the following NoServerForRegionException occurred. I've checked the status of master node on port 60010 and region server on port 60030. They are both working fine.

```
13/12/09 11:04:41 ERROR mapreduce.TableOutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test_summary,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
13/12/09 11:04:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://sandbox:8020/user/root/.staging/job_201312091058_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test_summary,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:970)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at com.ebay.traffic.opendata.hbasemapreduce.FreqCounter.main(FreqCounter.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for test_summary,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:832)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:201)
    ... 16 more
```

Could anybody suggest what the possible cause could be for the exception? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ignore - I did not read the question correctly.  are you running the same hbase versions?  might be useful to check times on all nodes and perhaps use NTP

Comment: What kind of situation are you seeing this? MR Job? Single thread client? Single get? Long scan? Also on what kind of machine is the server running?

Comment: Try checking the permissions. See the log files too for any clues. I'm pretty sure it's a permission issue. See library.path configuration that must point to the native libraries of Hadoop.